# Picocli: Best way to specify option with optional value that prints current value when no value specified

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, picocli

I'm writing a REPL (so I'm using picocli internally to parse commands typed within the application, not to parse command line args), and I have a command with an option that I want to behave like this:

```
> cmd --myopt
Myopt value = 5
> cmd --myopt 4
> cmd --myopt
Myopt value = 4
```

That is, if the option is specified with no value, the current value of the parameter is printed, but if it is specified with a value, then the value is set. I was thinking to do this like this:

```java
int value = 1; // default
@Option(names = {"-e", "--epsilon"}, arity = "0..1",
        description = "Acceptable values: [0, 1] default: ${DEFAULT-VALUE}")
void setValue(String strValue) {
    if (strValue == "") {
        printValue();
    } else {
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
            // validate value
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // print help for this option
        }
    }
}
```

Is that the best way? Is there another way to capture the default value in the description while still allowing `setValue` to know that no value was specified?

*(See also https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/490 )*

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up taking a different approach; it's helpful for my application to be able to directly assign to a field of the actual type (because we're developing a feature where you can "discover" commands that take arguments of various types, so having the field be the actual type makes this reverse lookup easier).

So I ended up doing this:

```
static class DoubleConverter implements ITypeConverter<Double> {
    public Double convert(String value) throws Exception {
        if(value.isEmpty()) return Double.NaN; // this is a special value that indicates the option was present without a value
        return Double.valueOf(value);
    }
}

@Option(names = {"-e", "--epsilon"}, arity="0..1", description="Acceptable values: [0, 1] default: 0.1", converter=DoubleConverter.class)
Double epsilon;
```

Basically, I use a converter to store a special value (NaN in this case, because we ended up using a double) to indicate that the option was present without a value (which is different than it not being present at all, in which case it would be null).

Then the validation and other behavior is performed in the `run()` method as you suggested:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // null indicates the option was not present, so do nothing
    if(epsilon != null) {
        // NaN indicates the option was present but with no value, which means we should print the current value
        if(epsilon.equals(Double.NaN)) {
            // print current value from the application
            printEpsilonValue();
        }
        else {
            // validate value
            if(epsilon < 0.0 || epsilon > 1.0) {
                throw new ParameterException(spec.commandLine(), "Invalid parameter value");
            } else {
                // set the value in the application
                setEpsilonValue(episilon);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

I wasn't able to specify the default value in the description using the variable, because  the actual default value in this case needs to be null. This is a minor sacrifice, though.

I realize this is an unusual case, but it might be nice to support this sort of option (non-boolean with arity 0..n) without the need to resort to special values. Perhaps the ability to specify another field to serve as the boolean value that indicates whether the option was present or not. Then there would be no need for a custom converter, either, and possibly the default could still be specified (i.e., the Double field in this case would get set to the default, but if the option was not present, the corresponding boolean field would be false, so the application would know not to use the value of the Double).

Comment: This reminds me of https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/280 . The suggested attribute name on that ticket was `implicit`, so you could declare an option like `@Option(names = "-e", arity = "0..1", implicit = "NaN") Double epsilon;`  Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: I think that would be a equivalent of what I implemented here via the custom converter. However, my suggestion is actually to provide a mechanism that would avoid needing to specify a special value at all (after all, there may be cases where no special value is available, like with a pre-defined enum). An example mechanism may be to specify another boolean field that gets set to true when the option is provided, and otherwise is false. Perhaps this field can be specified via another parameter in the annotation, or perhaps it can be annotated separately.

Comment: This is already available: the `ParseResult` object has several methods like `hasMatchedOption` that return whether the option was matched on the command line (see https://picocli.info/picocli-3.0-programmatic-api.html#_querying_for_options ). Would that meet your needs?

Comment: I think so, but the potential difficulty is that I was hoping to use `parseWithHandlers` with the `RunLast()` method, since it helps avoid a lot of boilerplate, but the `Runnable` that gets called doesn't get the `ParseResult` object. Is there a way to get the `ParseResult` object from my `Runnable`?

Comment: So, I was able to get the `ParseResult` in my `Runnable` by injecting the `CommandSpec` via the `@Spec` annotation, and then in my `Runnable` doing `ParseResult result = spec.getCommandLine().getParseResult();`. However, this reports that the option is present, even if it had no value, which is precisely the case I'm trying to distinguish.

Comment: I was finally able to get this to work like this: `boolean present = !result.matchedOption("--epsilon").originalStringValues().get(0).isEmpty();` I'm not sure this is very clear, although it could be wrapped in a helper method with a clear name, like `hasValue("--epsilon")`. Perhaps this is the way to go.

Comment: I’m thinking the annotations API is where an additional attribute can make the most difference. Something like `@Option(names=“-e”, arity=“0..1”, implicit=“1”)` or perhaps `@Option(..., valueWhenOmitted=“1”)` is a better name.

Comment: Is this different than specifying a default? It would be better to avoid default values entirely, as there may be no good default in some cases (e.g., with an enum, where every value is meaningful). Being able to access a boolean somewhere that explicitly says whether the option had a value or not is better. This is essentially achievable via the `ParseResult` as discussed above, but an annotation solution would be simpler. Perhaps `@Option(names="-e", arity="0..1", valueSetBoolean="myBooleanField")` where `valueSetBoolean `refers to another field in the same class as the option field.

Comment: The `defaultValue` is the value of the option when the option was not specified at all on the command line. The `implicitValue` would be the value of the option when the option name was specified without a value. I'm not sure I agree with the "there may not be a good implicit value when the type is an enum" argument: if the option value is optional you need an enum value that expresses the case when the value was omitted. Otherwise an enum is not the right type for that option (or the value should not be optional). I don't like the idea of one annotation modifying 2 fields...

Comment: It's true that if I were creating an enum specifically for the option, I could add a value for "unset". However, if I'm using an existing application-defined enum, then there may be no such value. Perhaps I shouldn't be doing that, but it does avoid the need to translate from one enum type to another. Another example would be if the value were an integer. It may be that all integers are valid, and hence there is no good integer to use as the implicit value. But probably in most cases we can sacrifice one integer (e.g., MAX_VALUE).

Comment: FYI, it still rubs me the wrong way that we essentially need to use "special" values to represent the semantics of missing value. Having a separate boolean (or directly inspecting the model) directly represents what we actually want to know. Perhaps we could introduce a new type, e.g., OptionalValue<type> that acts like a tri-state optional. The default value would be "not present", and then a converter could set it to "present but no value" or set the actual value.

Comment: Interesting idea! Please also mention it here https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/280 so @pditommaso can join the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly one way to do it. Bear in mind that the setter method may be called multiple times: once to reset the default values, and then again each time the option is matched on the command line.

An alternative is to change the field type to `String`, put the `@Option` annotation on the field, and call this logic (that is in the `setValue` method above) from your `run` or `call` method.